# Path to use to locate custom bash script in custom Homebrew cask?

Tags: homebrew

I have successfully installed a custom Homebrew cask using https://github.com/termsurf/homebrew-load:

```
$ brew install --cask termsurf/load/task
```

However, it fails at the [last step](https://github.com/termsurf/homebrew-load/blob/059d1b7e329fd466374eed6f2aa57e2ec01960b7/Casks/task.rb#L36):

```
system_command "install.sh"
```

I tried as well:

```
system_command "#{staged_path}/install.sh"
```

But both fail with corresponding errors:

```
Error: termsurf/load/task: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env install.sh` exited with 127. Here's the output:
env: install.sh: No such file or directory
```

What is the path to use to get access to that custom install script located at the base of my repo (or where should I put it in the repo)?